# increment and decrement the input value when click on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

am stuck with a problem , when I click on +,- button then qty value will be increase and decrease properly, but I also want when I click on increment and decrement button, price also will increment and decrement. i want to increment and decrement the value of price when click on + or - button

[image]

> index.html

This is the index.html file where i wrote my whole ui part

```
 <div class="container">
        <h3>Solar terrace light with inbuilt panel</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rzp-prod-merchant-assets/payment-link/description/pr11_hq0cy7e5cmwbzw"
                    class="w-75">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
                <div class="card p-4">
                    <h4>Payment Details</h4>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Qty.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <div class="quantity">
                                <button class="btn minus-btn disabled" type="button">-</button>
                                <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
                                <button class="btn plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
                            </div>

                            <!--will calculate price---->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Name</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Email</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Phone</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Price</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <p class="total-price">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-rupee-sign" style="color: black;"></i></span>
                                <input id="price" class="text-dark" value="12,999"> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> index.js

This is the index.js file where i wrote whole logic part for increment and decremnt

```
  document.querySelector(".minus-btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

        //taking value to increment decrement input value
        var valueCount

        //taking price value in variable
        var price = document.getElementById("price").innerText;

        //price calculation function
        function priceTotal() {
            var total = valueCount * price;
            document.getElementById("price").innerText = total
        }

        //plus button
        document.querySelector(".plus-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //getting value of input
            valueCount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

            //input value increment by 1
            valueCount++;

            //setting increment input value
            document.getElementById("quantity").value = valueCount;

            if (valueCount > 1) {
                document.querySelector(".minus-btn").removeAttribute("disabled");
                document.querySelector(".minus-btn").classList.remove("disabled")
            }

            //calling price function
            priceTotal()
        })

        //plus button
        document.querySelector(".minus-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //getting value of input
            valueCount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

            //input value increment by 1
            valueCount--;

            //setting increment input value
            document.getElementById("quantity").value = valueCount

            if (valueCount == 1) {
                document.querySelector(".minus-btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
            }

            //calling price function
            priceTotal()
        })
```

Comment: `innerText` is a custom property for `input` elements, use `value` instead. Also, decimal separator in JS is a dot `.`.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple things that will not work with your code, first, input values are all strings by default so you wont be able to multiply them you need to use `parseInt` (if you want it in integer) or `parseFloat` if you want the decimals.
Second thing, if you want the text in the input element you need to use ".value" instead of ".innerText" and third and last thing. If your product is 12999 you would need to put it in full number and only display it with a , in another code or use a . and make it work as a decimal only then replace your dot as a coma for the display

It would look like this on the HTML Side :

```
<div class="container">
        <h3>Solar terrace light with inbuilt panel</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/rzp-prod-merchant-assets/payment-link/description/pr11_hq0cy7e5cmwbzw"
                    class="w-75">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
                <div class="card p-4">
                    <h4>Payment Details</h4>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Qty.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <div class="quantity">
                                <button class="btn minus-btn disabled" type="button">-</button>
                                <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
                                <button class="btn plus-btn" type="button">+</button>
                            </div>

                            <!--will calculate price---->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Name</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Email</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Phone</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <p>Price</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <p class="total-price">
                                <span><i class="fas fa-rupee-sign" style="color: black;"></i></span>
                                <input id="price" class="text-dark" value="12.999"> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And like this on the Javascript side :

```
document.querySelector(".minus-btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

        //taking value to increment decrement input value
        var valueCount

        //taking price value in variable
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        console.log(price);

        //price calculation function
        function priceTotal() {
            var total = parseFloat(valueCount) * parseFloat(price);
            document.getElementById("price").value = total
        }

        //plus button
        document.querySelector(".plus-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //getting value of input
            valueCount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

            //input value increment by 1
            valueCount++;

            //setting increment input value
            document.getElementById("quantity").value = valueCount;

            if (valueCount > 1) {
                document.querySelector(".minus-btn").removeAttribute("disabled");
                document.querySelector(".minus-btn").classList.remove("disabled")
            }

            //calling price function
            priceTotal()
        })

        //plus button
        document.querySelector(".minus-btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
            //getting value of input
            valueCount = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

            //input value increment by 1
            valueCount--;

            //setting increment input value
            document.getElementById("quantity").value = valueCount

            if (valueCount == 1) {
                document.querySelector(".minus-btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
            }

            //calling price function
            priceTotal()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to "innerHtml" with "value" and remove the ","(comma) from the price. And that's it!